# Open Crystal Report with a parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Normally, I use Microsoft report and I can call parameter.

But for Crystal Report 2008 I want to call the report with a parameter to see the data from my bd on the report.

My report is bound to a data set.

Comment: you have to add a new parameter and set its properties.  Try searching the Crystal Help file for 'parameter'.  There's also lots of info on Google, you should be able to find examples to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following links will help you

[How to pass parameter in crystal report using dataset in vb.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1384708.aspx/1)

[Crystal Report Basics and Integration with DataSet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18332/Crystal-Report-Basics-and-Integration-with-DataSet)

[Display GridView in Crystal Report](http://forums.asp.net/p/1359067/2825312.aspx#2825312)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.